# python override a api class method with different name

Tags: python, python-3.x, callback, ctypes

first, create my own class object inherit the api

```
class mainobject1(XAPI):
    def __init__(self):
        XAPI.__init__(self)
        self.count = 0
        # built-in to run api
        self.run()
    # default api method name
    def error(self, regId, errorCode, errorString):
        print("Error:", errorCode)
        self.count += 1
```

this allows me to access self.count in "error" method, but is it possible to direct the API method "error" to other specific name like "xapi_error"? there are few api in my program so I wanna declare them clearly.
i simply do not want self.error be accessible in mainobject class.

so, create an api object separately

```
class myapi(XAPI):
    def __init__(self):
        XAPI.__init__(self)      
    # default api method name  
    def error(self, regId, errorCode, errorString):
        print("Error:", errorCode)
        # self.count += 1 # not working here
class mainobject2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.api = myapi()    
        self.count = 0
        # built-in to run api
        self.api.run()
```

this approach won't have naming issue but not straight-forward to access to my own class variable self.count.

Then I tried the followings:

```
......
class mainobject2():
    ......
    # Failed approach
    @self.api.error # <------ ERROR
    def xapi_error(self, regId, errorCode, errorString):
        ......
```

NameError: name 'self' is not defined

i had some success with this @ approach long ago but forget what it is and how to use it...

```
......
import ctypes
class mainobject2():
    # Failed approach
    def RegCallback(self):
        def xapi_error(None, regId, errorCode, errorString):
            ......
        self.xapi_ErrorAddr = PYFUNCTYPE(None, c_char_p)(xapi_error)
        self.app.error(self.xapi_ErrorAddr) # <------ ERROR
```

TypeError: error() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'errorCode' and 'errorString'

i am able to use ctypes to map the dll callback to my class...I wonder if there is something similar for python callback...

Ultimately, my structure:

```
mainobject(self)
├── objectx (self)
│      └── xapi
├── objecty (self)
│      └── yapi
......
```

self params shares with each other so can be accessed everywhere. so i hope, inside a thread code, it will be :

```
import XAPI
......
class objectx():
    def __init__(self):
        self.xapi = myxapi()
        self.xcount = 0
        # built-in to run api
        self.xapi.run()
    # answer to this question
    ......
    # then finally
    def xapi_error(self, regId, errorCode, errorString):
        print("Error:", errorCode)
        self.xcount += 1
    ......
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you handle the first error() call with the inputs?

Then you can do something like:

```
def error(self, regId, errorCode, errorString):
        print("Error:", errorCode)
        self.count += 1 # you can remove this and put it in another function
        if errorCode == 1: # whatever the error codes are
            self.xapi_error(.....)
        elif errorCode == 2:
            self.app_error(....)
        else:
            super().error(....)

def xapi_error(....):
    pass

def app_error(...):
    pass
```

Is this what you were looking for?

If you don't call the

```
super().error(...)
```

in your error function, it will not call the overridden method.

Comment: i simply want to override the name error() to xapi_error() but still have callback ability from API.